# How to make track-changes column/range specific

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range, trace

I have a table with a number of columns and rows in it and I would like to track the changes made in a specific column. I found the code (see bottom of message) online, and it works perfectly. However, it tracks “all changes”. Is there a way to make it range specific. For example I only want to track the changes made in the column with the red numbers. Please see the example:

[image]

The code I found online is the following:

```
Option Explicit

Dim vOldVal 'Must be at top of module

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim bBold As Boolean
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Pricing" Then Exit Sub
    'On Error Resume Next
    With Application
         .ScreenUpdating = False
         .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    If IsEmpty(vOldVal) Then vOldVal = "Empty Cell"
    bBold = Target.HasFormula
        With Sheets("Data")
            '.Unprotect Password:="Secret"
                If .Range("A96") = vbNullString Then
                    .Range("A96:H96") = Array("Cell Changed", "Old Value", _
                        "New Value", "Old Formula", "New Formula", "Time of Change")
                End If
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 1)
                  .Value = ActiveSheet.Name & " : " & Target.Address
                  .Offset(0, 1) = vOldVal
            With .Offset(0, 2)
              If bBold = True Then
                .ClearComments
                .AddComment.Text Text:= _
                     "OzGrid.com:" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & _
                        "Bold values are the results of formulas"
              End If
                .Value = Target
                .Font.Bold = bBold

            End With
                .Offset(0, 3) = Time
                .Offset(0, 4) = Date
                .Offset(0, 5) = Application.UserName
            End With
            .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
            '.Protect Password:="Secret"
        End With
    vOldVal = vbNullString
    With Application
         .ScreenUpdating = True
         .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        vOldVal = Target
End Sub


Private Sub test()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Please keep in mind that I'm very new to VBA coding.

Comment: Where do you want the changes tracked? What changes to you want tracked? Do you want the time it was changed? The old value?

Comment: I would like new value, old value, time, author, and cell number which was changed. 
I would like the location of the track-changes to be at A96:E96 in the same document as the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding a single line to your existing code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim bBold As Boolean
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Pricing" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 4 Then Exit Sub
```

This will just check to see if it is the 4th column of your sheet that has been changed and will ignore changes elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that worksheet changes are specific to one sheet so you do not need to test the sheet here. The `Target` will always and forever exist on the sheet that houses this code. It is a redundant check

Comment: So, that means you can reduce to `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 or Target.Column <> 4 Then Exit Sub`